# Something is blocking HTTP/unsecure downloads

Tags: internet, download, http, website

We have a problem where we can't download anything on unsecure websites (Primarily PDF and Excel documents)

Chrome comes up and says "Network error". Internet explorer downloads it, but corrupts the document.

We have Symantec Endpoint Protection, Heimdal and Advanced Security on our firewall.

Neither of the three has anything in their logs that they blocked it. I have tried to disable all web and download protection on Symantec, with no luck.

Anyone who has some ideas where this problem occurs?

**EDIT** What is even more weird is i CAN print to PDF and i can open it. But i can't directly download it.

Comment: Have you tried looking at a corrupt download with Notepad?  It may be that whatever is causing the problem isn't actually corrupting the data, but is replacing it completely with with something that may provide a clue.

Comment: @RandyOrrison It seems to be random numbers and letters (for me), with "correct" text inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the Advanced Security on the Meraki firewall we have. I could not download from my phone connected to the company WiFi, which has no anti-virus nor anything else. But when i disabled the security features i could both from my phone and my laptop.

This was also blocking Windows Update and Microsoft Store so these couldn't download or install anything.